# Trying to get vb code to accept partial string matches

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
Function SingleCellExtract(LookupValue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer, Char As String)
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRet As String
    For I = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
        If LookupRange.Cells(I, 1) = LookupValue Then
            If xRet = "" Then
                xRet = LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
            Else
                xRet = xRet & "" & LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
            End If
        End If
    Next
    SingleCellExtract = Left(xRet, Len(xRet) - 1)
End Function
```

The above code creates a function that allows you to enter a cell you want to match with a series of cells in a column and then allows you to enter the column number you want to return the value from based on the match. It can also return multiple values from that column seperated by a comma. I retrieved this from [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3120-excel-return-multiple-values-separated-by-comma.html) webpage. Right now, it only returns exact matches to the selected cell, I want to expand it to include partial matches. I have tried editing it to use the Like operator and accept wildcards, but it doesn't seem to work. The selected cell generally contains a string in the form of A9000, P-6000, P-6000-AL. My version still only retrieves that exact same string from the column. If I enter P9000, I'd also like it to retrieve LP9000, A9000, BL-9000-76, PDP 9000, etc just as an example. Does anyone know how I could achieve this using this code or is there a better alternative? Thank you

Comment: Before you (or we) can solve this, you need to define precisely how a *match* is defined. Just by the number?

Comment: look at `instr`

Comment: Sorry, yes. The match would be defined by that 4 digit number.

Comment: If you have office 365 vba is not necessary.

Comment: You say that you tried `Like` but you don't show that attempt or what about it didn't work. That is the answer to your question so please show us what you are doing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator